# Can I build/install extensions for Chrome OS (i.e. not for Chrome browser)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

The on-line docs imply that extensions are only applicable to the Chrome browser.  However, some APIs could be used to extend the Chrome OS.  For example, fileBrowserHandler can be used to extend the Chrome OS file browser. If this is true then how would I build/install an extension for the OS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome OS in not really separable from the browser. That's the idea.

So you don't install extensions separately from the browser; it's just that special APIs are exposed on Chrome OS.